# Why can't i use unity's audioMixer like that?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I'm using the audioMixer to change the pitch and the highest possible frequenzes.
My mixer looks like this [image]

And here's some code to set the exposed parameters:

```
public void setSoundDamping(bool isDamped) {
   soundMixer.SetFloat("Cutoff Frequenzes", isDamped ? 600f : 22000f);
}

public void setSoundPitch(bool isSlow) {
   soundMixer.SetFloat("Pitch", isSlow ? .75f : 1f);
}
```

The problem is, that after changing the paramters back and fourth one or more times some extremely weird sound glitches emerge. Like the music playing stops for a couple seconds sometimes and the volume also changes randomly. The soundeffects also sometimes dissapear or make weird noises.

When looking at the parameters "look" good. So is there anything i'm doing fundamentally wrong with this approach? Or may this even be a bug with Unity itself?

PS: i have like 15 differnet GameObjects, that emmit sound and have this mixer set as their mixer to use.